# Creating a simple application involving iteration, and something is off. Likely an easy fix.

Tags: c#, html, if-statement, for-loop, iteration

I am creating a simple application where I ask the user to specify which number to iterate to, and how many rows they want outputted. I think I'm really close, but fairly new at this, so I'm sure a little syntax and variable tweaking will get me there. I am creating this in .Net using MVC. I receive an error upon running because "x" and "y" names do not show up. Here is what I have:

```
<body>
<div> 

    @{


        var numCount = x;
        var colCount = y; 

        for (int i = 1; i < numCount; i++)
        {
            <span>@i</span>

            if (i % colCount == 0)
            {
                <br />
                    <form id="myForm">
                        How many numbers would you like to iterate to?
                        <br/>
                        <input id="x" type="text" name="x" />
                        <br/>
                        How many rows would you like in your iteration?
                        <br />
                        <input id="y" type="text" name="y" />
                        <br />
                        <input type="submit" value="Calculate!" onsubmit="return i()" />
                    </form>

            }
        }



    }

</div>
```

Comment: You cant set x and y variable equal to the ID of your Input. You will need to use some jquery and have two views, or a separate view to accept X and Y, and another view to iterate over the passed variables.  X and Y have not been set when setting numCount and colCount. Are you using a model?

Comment: I am not using a model, just a controller to populate the view, and was attempting to make it all happen in one View if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X and Y have not been set once numCount and colCount are set.  I would move this into two views or do something with jquery and ajax.

Here is the two view solution.

Create a a class and add two properties of ints (x and y). Have a seperate view that binds X and Y to separate inputs.

```
public class Iterator
    {
        public int x { get; set; }

        public int y { get; set; }
    }
```

Create a second view like your first that accepts the Model. Then your second view will look something like this:

```
@Model Iterator

<div>

    @{


        var numCount = Model.x;
        var colCount = Model.y;

        for (int i = 1; i < numCount; i++)
        {
            <span>@i</span>
            Do more stuff here.

        }


    }

</div>
```

I assume you can bind a simple POST view to X and Y and forward to this iteration view. if not let me know.

Edit: Here is what the first view could look like:

```
@Model Iterator

@Html.BeginForm("SecondView", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post)
{


   How many numbers would you like to iterate to?
   @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.x)

   <br />
   How many rows would you like in your iteration?
   @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.y)

<br />
<input type="submit" value="Calculate!">
}
```

Now just create the controller methods and your good to go! Note they can be HTTPGet, its up to you.

Comment: Worked out! Thanks for the help and tips!

Comment: @HerbalChaos420 Glad I could help! Good luck with your next project.